# Add CNAME or TXT records from AWS in GoDaddy

Tags: dns, cname

how to add CNAME or TXT records from AWS or something in GoDaddy?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CNAME

In the "Host" field enter Name from AWS **_ede669291a50b22db41fe58b6251521b.www** (without the host name) if it's a subdomain like "_ede669291a50b22db41fe58b6251521b.test.steelcity.xyz" then enter **_ede669291a50b22db41fe58b6251521b.test**

In the Points to field enter Value from the AWS (**_0da75843sxddfgsgsdd6ce1.acm-validations.aws**)

[image]

If you want to create a record for TXT then do not include the host name in the Host field i.e. to create a TXT record for "_ede669291a50b22db41fe58b6251521b.steelcity.xyz" you just enter without the domain name **_ede669291a50b22db41fe58b6251521b**